# php variable name as string

Tags: php, echo

I make a function for put in an array all php variable in a file (.php)

In the array, I want something like this:

```
$myvariable = 'hello man';
```

So I do:

```
$myarray['$variable'] = $variable;
```

For have:

```
array('$myvariable' => 'hello man', '$othervariable' => 'in the space...');
```

I want "print" the array like this:

```
 foreach($myarray as $key =>$value){
    echo $key.' -> '.$value.'<br>';
 }
```

When I do:

```
$myarray['$variable'] = $variable;
$myarray["$variable"] = $variable; //don't work because "
$myarray[$variable]   = $variable; //the key is change in value
```

don't stay as the variable name but as the value.

How to have the variable name as string??

Comment: Why are you quoting the variable in the first place? Just use `$myarray[$variable]`.

Comment: I _think_ what you're looking for is `array('\$myvariable' => 'hello man', ... );` and `$myarray['\$variable'] = $variable;`